# Uncountability of a nonmeasurable set

Tags: analysis, proof-writing

As per the Vitali's theorem, every measurable set of positive measure has a subset which is nonmeasurable. Which proceeds by defining a rational equivalence, followed by using the axiom of choice on the collection of equivalence classes. This choice set is a non-measurable set, as per the theorem. How can I prove it's uncountability?

Answer (score 4):

Every countable set has measure zero, so any nonmeasurable set must be uncountable.

Comment: Mario, it is obvious (please don't take me wrong) that the set is uncountable, which is why I need a proper argument for uncountability of the choice set. (A set whose elements differ by irrational numbers)

Comment: @Siddhu.  No, you don't.  Mario answered your question completely.